# Linq entity using where clause twice in a row

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have some code where I apply a "where clause" like this:

I put in "n" as an example of the database table.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> n = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,2));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,3));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4,6));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4,3));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,3));

var zzz = n.Where(z => z.Key == 1); // this returns "1,2" and "1,3"
```

Then somewhere else in my code I did this:

```
zzz.Where(x => x.Value == 3); // this should return "1,3"... Instead it seems to return "4,3" and "5,3" and "1,3".
```

Isn't the second Where supposed to return only "1,3"??? The second Where clause, should be applied to the result of the "zzz" shouldn't it?

Comment: It should, and as far as I can see, it does. Could you give a complete - reproducible - example?

Comment: It should, tested:

`var zzz = n.Where(z => z.Key == 1);` and `var yyy = zzz.Where(z => z.Value == 3);`. When I spit out the results of yyy I only get [1, 3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second Where clause, should be applied to the result of the "zzz" shouldn't it?

Yes, and it in fact does.  Take this sample code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> n = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,2));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,3));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4,6));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4,3));
n.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,3));

var zzz = n.Where(z => z.Key == 1); // this returns "1,2" and "1,3"

zzz = zzz.Where(x => x.Value == 3); // this then filters to the 2nd option

foreach(var pair in zzz)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

This prints `1:3`, as expected.

I suspect the problem may be that you're not re-assigning the results of the second filter: `zzz.Where(x => x.Value == 3);`  The result of that needs to be assigned to a variable (or enumerated) in order to see the actual, filtered results.

Comment: @Xander Isn't that what I said in my last paragraph?

Comment: Yeah that is strange, because I have a function that returns a List<table> x... Then I do x.Where on it, and use "SingleOrDefault", and it returns an exception saying "sequence contains more than one element." When I look through the database on the exact query, there is only ONE. Strange.

Comment: @Dexter Split it into two calls, so the `SingleOrDefault` is on it's own call.  Debug and see what you're getting in the sequence before that.  You're obviously getting more than one result.

Comment: So now I undid my "FirstOrDefault" and put back the singleOrDefault, and the error is gone. Like as if before it was operating on old data.